# The best practice of using Google Tag Manager among different domains and co-workers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I can’t wrap my mind around which account and container hierarchy in Google Tag Manager is best for my needs or – to be more precise – if it’s feasible to use multiple containers for different purposes on a single domain.

This is my initial situation:

- We have a couple of dozen domains maintained by different colleagues.
- I’d like to have one container which deals with the “must-haves” every webpage of our company needs (e.g.  tracking cookies, Google Analytics, Remarketing Pixels,  you know the deal).
- On the other hand, I’d like to give my co-workers the freedom to have their own container with which they can gather their own experiences using Google Tag Manager (defining own events, page adjustments, etc.).

Am  I on the right path with my thoughts? Did you have similar questions? What was your solution? Are there any pitfalls with implementing two containers on a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager (GTM) creates one container when you add an account, therefore, you should use one. The way GTM works there should never ever be any need for more than one container since data can be organised through the use of 'folders', it is [not optimal to use multiple containers](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/multiple-gtm-containers-on-the-page/), in fact, it increases the page load time as you are loading multiple scripts.

If you intend to use multiple users but do not want users to access certain tags then it's not possible in one container, however, maybe your approach is all wrong. Ideally, you should add users as 'editors' and then you have superiors approve those edits with 'approve' user rights, that way, all edits can be reviewed before publishing and it should minimize issues from bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user management section in your **account**.
If you want your co-workers to have access to specific containers, then use the user management section under the container section of admin.